# Managing Multiple Pages for React Application

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

We have flask/python based application and everything about the application is managed by flask (including user sessions, URLs, etc).

Now we are building one UI component for the application which is built using reactjs. So, we build the react bundle (bundle.js), and render it inside a page in our flask application. This works well.

Our problem is this - The next version of our react app has multiple screens. And the user generally goes from one screen to the next in a flow and sometimes may want to access a particular screen directly.

My question is - How we we manage these multiple pages without losing performance or having to reload the react component while changing screens? It's important for us that flask continues to manage the main URLs. Also, I don't mind if the react screens don't have a URL as long as I can traverse between the screens through links within the react component.

I've tried to show the structure of our app in the below diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried embedding React within a Flask application myself, but it may be worthwhile to use  [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) for the React app.

You can keep using Flask to manage the URLs. In this case, Flask will return your React application, but the React application routing itself will be managed by React-Router.

React-Router will wipe the state clean each time you switch pages, which is why you need to save the application's state either by using React's state/props system or (preferably) through a framework like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/index.html).

This seems like the most straightforward way of doing it. I've built a few multi-page web applications in React from scratch and from my experience it shouldn't take that much time to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

As @PiggyBoy said, you should probably look at client-side routing such as React-Router, and also have the current state of the app kept in Redux, Flux or any other.

How you could do it in your Flask app, and how I have done for most of my Flask/React projects is:

```
from flask import render_template, make_response
from mysite import app

@app.route('/path-to-react-app/', defaults={ 'path': '' })
@app.route('/path-to-react-app/<path:path>/')
@login_required # if needed
def react_app(path):
    response = make_response(render_template(
        'react_app.html',
        path=path
    )
    response.set_cookie('your_cookie_if_needed', token_if_needed)

    return response
```

And in your React app you will have something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/path-to-react-app' component={App}>
            <Route path='some-page' component={PageComponent} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

And you can then use react-router's `Link` in order to link your components together